# How to get data inside data in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
{"dynamic_link_data":{"data":{"referralCode":"1234"}}}
```

How to get referralCode inside data. I m not able to fetch referralCode from response.

Comment: do you have multiple `dynamic_link_data` in your response?

Comment: no. Only this much

Comment: var referralCode = data["dynamic_link_data"]!["data"]!["referralCode"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one `dynamic_link_data` and also one `data`, you can try this:

```
var test = {"dynamic_link_data":{"data":{"referralCode":"1234"}}};

if (test.isNotEmpty && test.entries.first.value.isNotEmpty) {
  print(test.entries.first.value.entries.first.value['referralCode']);
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'entries'.

Comment: getting this kind of error

Comment: put your response inside `jsonDecode` then use it, like this:  `var test = jsonDecode(response)` @wolfsoftDeveloper

Comment: {"dynamic_link_data":{"data":{"referralCode":"1234","Username":"ABC"}}}


What in case of multiple params ?

Comment: there is no issue with the one you provide. @wolfsoftDeveloper

Comment: as long as those params wasn't inside the two previous `Map`. @wolfsoftDeveloper